# PHP while with sleep loop not updating database until end of loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, sleep, flush

I have a while loop with a sleep function that I wan´t to run -> update database -> sleep -> run again for a number of 10 times. With the below script the script loops 10 times, but it only updates the database when all 10 loops have finished.

I added an echo at the end just to verify, and the echo does not appear on the page until the and when every loop is echoed out at once.

I have also tried placing **ob_flush()** and **flush()** after the echo with no luck.

**Script**

```
$loops = 10;
while ($loops > 0)
{
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    // Get current User status
    $username = $row['username'];
    $user_status = $row['user_status'];
    $user_updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // Update database
    $update_sql = "UPDATE  `database`.`user` SET  `user_status` =  '$user_status',
                                                  `user_updated` =  '$agent_updated'
                                            WHERE  
                                                  `user`.`username` =  '$username'";
    $update=mysql_query($update_sql);
    echo "Loop #".$loops."<br>";
  }
flush();
$loops--;
Sleep(5);
}
```

I've also tried the same with a **FOR loop**.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. I've gone through the search and haven´t found users with similar issues but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: You can't get echoes one by one. What PHP does is output the entire thing at once, not one part at the time. So in turn, you'll wait for sleep() amount of seconds before you see the output on your screen.

Comment: If PHP only returns the output at the end, would you recommend haveing a seconds script that calls this page in a loop (calls the page every 5 seconds)?

Comment: That's one way to do it, however I don't know what your actual goal is. There is always more than one way to do something, you should describe what you have and what you want, maybe you'll get useful input from other people :)

Comment: Are you sure that it updates the database when all 10 loops have finished? Or do you just see the last update in db? Is it right to have one while cycle inside of the other one? Where is the $result coming from?

Comment: Good question. with every update there is a time-stamp in the database so I can monitor the update while the page is looping. The echo at the end of the loop also only returns the ech after all the loops. I also tried using a FOR loop and then a WHILE loop with no change.

Comment: Would having a PHP page with a include_once that includes that script every 5 seconds work, or is there a better way to call a php file every 5 seconds? (NOTE: I have a cronjob running every 1 minute, but need a loop to run the script every 5 seconds).

Comment: @Brian Warshaw - That script is just an example. I´m at least not using the *. I´m selecting only the columns I need.

Comment: @SkuliAxelson - one day you'll be the guy who will alter a table to add a few columns and you'll change all of your source files to reflect that. Just pray that the project you'll be working on isn't big or you'll curse the day when you read that you shouldn't use `SELECT *`.

Comment: @Brian Warshaw - Thanks, I do really appreciate constructive information. I´ll make sure to read up on mysqli and PDO. I just didn't know of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by `N.B.` that PHP only returns results all at once after the script runs, I have ended with the following solution:

A bash.sh script that runs the PHP page every 5 seconds:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
count=1
while [ $count -le 12 ] :
do
  # run this scripts for one minute (12 times every 5 seconds = 60 seconds)
  /usr/bin/php -q thescript.php
  (($count++))
sleep 5
done
```

Then a cronjob that runs the page every minute. The above works and solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can get those echoes to show one by one, but on a controlled environment (according to php documentation, flush may still buffer the output on several Win32 systems), you can read further in the [php flush manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php).

To be more specific, make sure APaches mod_gzip is disabled, also, some php.ini settings like output_buffering and zlib.output_compression should be set to false.

```
output_buffering = false
zlib.output_compression = false
```

Even with all of this, you may also need to send a "big" amount of data (like 2048 chars) in order to make some browser to actually display new data.

```
echo "One"
echo str_repeat(" ", 2048);
Sleep(3)
echo "Two"
echo str_repeat(" ", 2048);
// Ans so on
```

In the comments of the aforementioned  manual page, you can see more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I decided to use a bash script to run the PHP script every 5 seconds instead of relying on clearing a large buffer in PHP. Still, this is good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems, according to the code provided, that all updates are done in the first loop, then mysql_fetch_array($result) returns only falses and the inner loop is not proceeded again in the other main loops, unless you fill $result again (between while cycle headers).

Comment: This is so true. Didn´t notice that before. Thanks for correcting that. If PHP wouldn't wait with echoing out everything until the script ends, I shure would have needed to fix that.